# What is a 3-pole cable?

Tags: audio

This may seem a little dumbfounded but I asked someone if it was safe to use a 2.5mm - 3.5mm cable converter on both ends of a male 3.5mm cable, and they told me it was alright as long as it was a 3-pole plug. What exactly is a 3-pole plug? I'm trying to substitute a 2.5mm male to male cable for (2) 2.5mm to 3.5mm converters and a 3.5mm cable.

I'm sorry if this question isn't clear, I'm really not sure how to word something like this. Also I'm sorry if this is the wrong section (or website)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but to me it looks like 3-pole plug refers to the usual Tip Ring Sleeve 6.35mm, 3.5 mm or 2.5 mm plug. There are also variations such as tip sleeve and tip ring ring sleeve and similar plugs.

Here's a picture from the Wikipedia of such plugs:

[image: TS and TRS connectors]

Going from left to right, we have a 2.5 mm tip sleeve connector, 3,5 mm tip sleeve connector, 3.5 mm tip ring sleeve connector and 6.35 mm tip ring sleeve connector.

Usually, the tip ring sleeve 3.5 mm is the default plug for consumer stereo audio, so you'd need a matching 2.5 mm plug.

The poles part probably comes from internal connections of the connectors. Usually each section (tip, rings and sleeve) are electrically isolated from each other and each can carry a single signal.